# How do call a function which pass different values to function without inline onclick attribute of HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, web-applications

I create a list of buttons generated by **PHP** script that call a function with different value passing to the function.

```
<button id="_n1" onclick="pass(111)">Number 1</button>
<button id="_n2" onclick="pass(222)">Number 2</button>
<button id="_n3" onclick="pass(333)">Number 3</button>
<button id="_n4" onclick="pass(444)">Number 4</button>
<button id="_n5" onclick="pass(555)">Number 5</button>
<button id="_n6" onclick="pass(666)">Number 6</button>
```

like the above code.

The onclick="pass(111)" such like codes are appear in developer tool.
I want to hide that in devloper tool. for security purpose.

It is possible with javascript for a dynamic webpages ...?

I inspected some shopping website
Href links or onclick function call or not shown in that sites.

How do achieve this..?

**I want like this code.**

```
<button id="_n1">Number 1</button>
<button id="_n2">Number 2</button>
<button id="_n3">Number 3</button>
<button id="_n4">Number 4</button>
<button id="_n5">Number 5</button>
<button id="_n6">Number 6</button>
```

But this code will call a function which pass different value.

It is possible with AddEventListenner in javascript...?

Please help for a small developer Kid :)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers. However, this does not hide the information; if some data needs to be kept secret, it must not be sent to the client at all.

```js
let pass = console.log; // for demonstration
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  document.getElementById('_n' + i).addEventListener('click', e => pass(i * 111));
}
```

```html
<button id="_n1">Number 1</button>
<button id="_n2">Number 2</button>
<button id="_n3">Number 3</button>
<button id="_n4">Number 4</button>
<button id="_n5">Number 5</button>
<button id="_n6">Number 6</button>
```